# CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 vs Indy10 TIdHMACSHA256.HashValue

Tags: javascript, delphi, cryptojs, indy10

I've been spending a day or two on this issue - I've cut the code to the bare bones minimum that's needed. Both functions are returning a different output, even though the input is the same.

The delphi code generates a result similar to: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html

Is there any known issue with either the CryptoJS or Delphi's Indy10 sha256 hashing code that might explain the different results in this case?

JS:

```
    function SetHashMessage(message_str)
    {
            var APIKey = "test";
            var signature_hash_obj = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message_str.toString(), APIKey);
            var signature_str = signature_hash_obj.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
            return signature_str;
    }
```

Delphi:

```
    function FDoHashMessageString(MessageString: String): String;
    var
        hmac: TIdHMACSHA256;
        hash: TIdBytes;
    begin
        LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
        if not TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
            raise Exception.Create('SHA256 hashing is not available: ' + WhichFailedToLoad());

        hmac := TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
        try
            hmac.Key := ToBytes('test');
            hash := hmac.HashValue(ToBytes(MessageString));
            Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(hash); // EncodeBytes returns base64
        finally
            hmac.Free;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Try again with an array of bytes, not a String (on both sides: JS and Delphi) - you just think it's the same input, but  it isn't.

Comment: You did not say which Delphi version you are using. It makes a big difference whether `String` is `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString`. Also, you are calling Indy's `ToBytes()` function without a byte encoding, so it will use the encoding specified by the `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit, which is set to US-ASCII by default. If your input string contains non-ASCII characters, you should use UTF-8 instead, either by setting `GIdDefaultTextEncoding=encUTF8`, or by passing `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` to `ToBytes()` (or just using `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes()` directly).

Comment: If the message string is multiline string you also need to take platform specific line endings into account - `CR` vs `CRLF`.

Comment: Delphi 7, and the solution was to use BytesToString rather than encodebytes it seems.